# Query about App Overflow Issue when Running from Branch vs Firebase App Distribution

Tags: flutter

I have encountered an issue and would appreciate your insights. When I run my app from a branch, I notice an overflow problem. However, when I install the same build from Firebase app distribution on the same devices, with the exact same font settings, the overflow issue disappears, and the app looks perfect.

I'm curious to understand the reasons behind this behavior. Has anyone else experienced a similar situation? Any thoughts or suggestions on how to address this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all for your time and assistance.